# Sending RF codes to 433 learning relay

Tags: wireless, relay

I have this RF learning relay
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuFzDcIiDxQ this is how relay learns codes.

However I don't have remote and want to control it using Pi. I've tried sending various codes using [433Utils](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils) with no luck.

Clicking learn button 8 times seem to correctly clear codes, at least LED flashing indicates it. But after this LED is flashing with any code I send to it and to my understanding it should ignore everything after code wipe.

Either I'm doing something completely wrong or receiver might be broken. Hopefully someone has dealt with these and gonna know how to troubleshoot it.

Process (click = single press of code learning button on relay):

- 8 clicks to clear codes
- LED flashes to indicate codes cleared
- 2 clicks to enter toggle learning mode (after each click LED blinks once)
- LED turns solid and waits for RF signal to learn
- send `11111` using [433Utils](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils) (signal is definitely sent, tested by listening with [pilight](https://www.pilight.org/))
- LED flashes and turns off

Expected: learning is complete, sending `11111` should blink LED once and toggle relay, sending other codes should do nothing

Outcome: sending any code including `11111` is making LED flash and not toggling relay

Comment: It may be a timing repeatability problem.  Try my http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python__433_py (sudo pigpiod first) which will send accurately timed signals.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that this evening. I've spent hours on google, but everyone just use remotes with these relays, not codes generated with Pi. And I need to use relay for now until micro-controller development kit arrives.

Comment: @joan Hi. I have specific question. Does your python library works with Manchester code? I have Arduino sending code using https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino-libs-manchester/blob/master/Manchester.h but receive nothing on Pi. I've connected cable directly between Arduino sending pin and Pi receiving pin to eliminate transceiver. This setup does work with Arduino using https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch/blob/master/RCSwitch.cpp instead of Manchester. Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the examples use Manchester encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[joan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13650/joan) was correct and it was timing issue. I've used suggested class and it worked.

Followed [pigpio installation](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html) instructions:

```
rm master.zip
sudo rm -rf pigpio-master
wget https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd pigpio-master
make
sudo make install
```

- Copied `_433.py` to my raspberry
- Updated `RX` and `TX` values at the end of the file to the GPIO I'm using
  for receiver and transmitter
- Executed `python _433.py 8246180` while relay being in learning mode
- Everything works as expected.

My hat's off to you sir! Still need to learn a lot about RF, but hopefully this post will help others using same learning relay.

Relay is know as:
`1 Channel 12V 433MHZ Receiver Wireless Relay RF`, `KR1201A`

EDIT:
You actually not required to build `pigpio` from source and actually I had to switch to repo version to run it on boot. Here's code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pigpio python-pigpio python3-pigpio
sudo systemctl enable pigpiod.service
```