# Transmit 433 MHz Manchester from Arduino - receive on Rasberry Pi

Tags: arduino, radio

On Attiny85 I'm using [Manchester encoding library](https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino-libs-manchester/blob/master/Manchester.h) with code

```
#include <Manchester.h>

#define TX_PIN 1

uint8_t transmit_data = 123;

void setup() {
  man.workAround1MhzTinyCore();
  man.setupTransmit(TX_PIN, MAN_1200);
}

void loop() {
  man.transmit(transmit_data);
  delay(800);
}
```

On Arduino I'm receiving `123` by using serial monitor

```
#include <Manchester.h>

#define RX_PIN 2

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  man.setupReceive(RX_PIN, MAN_1200);
  man.beginReceive();
}

void loop() {
  if (man.receiveComplete()) {
    uint8_t m = man.getMessage();
    Serial.println(m);
    man.beginReceive();
  }
}
```

On Pi I'm using [Python library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python__433_py) with code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import pigpio
import _433

RX=23

def rx_callback(code, bits, gap, t0, t1):
  print("code={} bits={} (gap={} t0={} t1={})".
     format(code, bits, gap, t0, t1))

pi = pigpio.pi() # Connect to local Pi.

rx=_433.rx(pi, gpio=RX, callback=rx_callback)

time.sleep(60)

rx.cancel() # Cancel the receiver.

pi.stop() # Disconnect from local Pi.
```

I'm expecting to receive `123`, but nothing happens. I've also tried different `MAN_` values with no luck.

**Second test**

On Arduino I'm using [RCSwitch library](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch) with code

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  mySwitch.enableTransmit(7);
  mySwitch.setProtocol(1);
}

void loop() {
  mySwitch.send(2222, 24);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Same setup on Pi and I'm receiving correct code.

The author of Python library [believes it should work with Manchester](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78864/sending-rf-codes-to-433-learning-relay/78899#comment125744_78864), so there is definitely issue with Pi receiving configuration, as Arduino receives message, but Pi doesn't.

[Video while testing using receiver and transmitter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6plGqCcnnA)

**Update:**

By reading through source code of all libraries, I'm pretty positive these are not compatible.

[Manchester is generating this wave form](https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino-libs-manchester/blob/master/Manchester.cpp#L186) using phase-shift

[image]

And RCSwitch is using [pulse length technique](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch/blob/master/RCSwitch.cpp#L55) generate this wave

[image]

I don't have oscilloscope so can't test my theory and assume this is how it works by reading comments in source.

In case Manchester encoding is happening somewhere behind the achene, the other issue could be sync transmission during which receiver adjust to transmission. These are completely different in two classes from looking into source.

Comment: Two things.  1. The Pi's GPIO are all 3V3 safe only.  Make sure you don't feed a 5V Arduino pin directly into a Pi GPIO. 2. Have you connected the grounds?

Comment: Yes both powered from same power supply. The setup doesn't change, only sketch on Arduino: RCSwitch works, Manchester doesn't. Also tested with transmitter and receiver attached - same results

Comment: I've also added link to YouTube, showing how I test setup. Please ignore `4315513` message in a video - this is my other project.

Comment: I've managed to transmit and receive data between Attiny85 and Arduino, still no luck on receiving data using Python library.

Comment: Have you used (my) piscope or similar to capture the signal received from a good source and compared it with the signal you are transmitting?

Comment: I've update question with my observations. I'll try setuping arduino analogue input to read what is being transmitted by on Attiny TX pin to confirm this theory.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work, so oped out to use second Attiny85 as controller for receiving and sending RF messages while receiving and sending commands to RPI using UART

Comment: What code are you using on the Attiny?  I'd like to compare it with what I do.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/50755/43756 this for interfacing with RPI and code from the above for actual sending and receiving.